# Conditional Distribution of $X-Y$ given $X > Y$ when $X$ follows exponential distribution

Tags: conditional-probability, exponential-distribution

Suppose $X$ follows exponential distribution with a positive parameter $\lambda$ and $Y$ is a positive continuous random variable, independent of $X$. Then what is the conditional distribution of $X-Y$ given $X > Y$?

Comment: The distribution of $X-Y$ truncated to the positive half-line.

Comment: It's quite straightforward (trivial, even) -- just use the lack of memory property.

Comment: @Glen_b I know the memorylessness property of exponential random variable. But here $Y$ is also a random variable. Does it matter?

Comment: It makes no difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the distribution of [$X\vert X>Y$](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48496/conditional-expectation-of-exponential-random-variable) or the [memorylessness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Memorylessness). Then see if it is easy to change it to $X-Y\vert X>Y$

> But here Y is also a random variable. Does it matter?

If you know $\mathbb{P}(A \vert B)$ and $B$ is itself a random variable, then you can find the probability of $\mathbb{P}(A)$ as a [compound distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_probability_distribution) or by using the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability)

$$\mathbb{P}(A) = \sum_{\forall B}  \mathbb{P}(A \vert B)\mathbb{P}(B) $$

if $ \mathbb{P}(A \vert B) = f(A)$ is a function independent of $B$ then it can be taken out of the sum and you get

$$\mathbb{P}(A) = \sum_{\forall B}  \mathbb{P}(A \vert B)\mathbb{P}(B)  = f(A)\sum_{\forall B}  \mathbb{P}(B) = f(A)  $$

Similarly when $\mathbb{P}(X-Y\vert X>Y, Y)$ is independent from $Y$ then you know  $\mathbb{P}(X-Y\vert X>Y)$

Comment: Just complementing, here he is using the Law of total probability.

Comment: @igorkf I knew that I was using some sort of 'well known law with a name', but I couldn't get the name.