Conditional Remaining Time to Event Paradox
The conditional expected time remaining for an event to occur seems to grow with waiting time. This seems either wrong or like some sort of paradox.
Let's take the Lomax distribution as an example. Assume that we are waiting for an event and the waiting time for events is distributed as
$$f(x)=\frac{a}{b}\left[1+\frac{x}{b}\right]^{-(a+1)}$$
with $a>2$ and $b>0$. Also assume that we have observed at time $T$ that the event has not yet occurred. The conditional density for the waiting time becomes
$$f(x|x\geq T)=\frac{f(x)}{f(x\geq T)}=\frac{f(x)}{1-f(x< T)}=\frac{\frac{a}{b}\left[1+\frac{x}{b}\right]^{-(a+1)}}{\left[1+\frac{T}{b}\right]^{-a}}$$
The expected value of the waiting time given we have observed the event has not occurred at time $T$ is
$$E[X|x\geq T]=\int_{T}^{\infty}xg(x|x\geq T)=\left[1+\frac{T}{b}\right]^{a}\int_{T}^{\infty}\frac{a}{b}x\left[1+\frac{x}{b}\right]^{-(a+1)}dx$$
The integral can be evaluated using integration by parts.
$$\int_{T}^{\infty}\frac{a}{b}x\left[1+\frac{x}{b}\right]^{-(a+1)}dx=-x(1+\frac{x}{b})^{-a}\vert_{T}^{\infty}+\frac{b}{-a+1}(1+\frac{x}{b})^{-a+1}\vert_{T}^{\infty}$$
$$=T(1+\frac{T}{b})^{-a}-\frac{b}{-a+1}(1+\frac{T}{b})^{-a+1}$$
I have used the following manipulation to evaluate the expression at $\infty$.
$$x(1+\frac{x}{b})^{-a}=x^{-a}x^{a+1}(1+\frac{x}{b})^{-a}=x^{a+1}\left[x(1+\frac{x}{b})\right]^{-a}=x^{a+1}\left[\frac{x^{2}}{b}+x\right]^{-a}$$
It should be clear that this goes to zero as $x\rightarrow\infty$ for $a>2$, though it could be more rigorous.
Then finally the expected value is
$$\left[1+\frac{T}{b}\right]^{a}\left[T(1+\frac{T}{b})^{-a}-\frac{b}{-a+1}(1+\frac{T}{b})^{-a+1}\right]=T+\frac{b}{a-1}\left[1+\frac{T}{b}\right]^{a}$$
If we care about the waiting time after the observation as opposed to the total waiting time that is
$$\frac{b}{a-1}\left[1+\frac{T}{b}\right]^{a}$$
So the expected additional waiting time after we take note the event has not occurred yet grows, at minimum, quadratically ($a>2$) with the time of our observation. This seems very counter intuitive to me. Typically if you've waited a while for an event to occur and it hasn't yet, you assume it will occur soon. I'm wondering if I've missed something or messed something up? Maybe this is the result of the Lomax distribution having a heavy tail? Is there an intuitive explanation for this result?

The longer you wait, the more likely it becomes that the event is a rare one: what is counter-intuitive about that?  Regardless, when there appears to be a conflict between your intuition and your model, then you shouldn't just question the intuition: maybe the model's not the right one for the phenomenon you are reasoning about.

This is true for the exponential distribution as well. However, conditional expected time remaining for that distribution is constant which is an intuitive result to me. (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48496/conditional-expectation-of-exponential-random-variable) It sounds like you are saying the math is right and the polynomial growth is a result of assumed distribution?

Math is math--it means nothing by itself.  When you assume a waiting time distribution as a model for a phenomenon, then you have either to accept its mathematical consequences or conclude that distribution is not an accurate model.
